# can i ask questions here about ElasticSearch?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'm doing lots of development with ElasticSearch and I have lots of questions. Can I ask those questions here?

Example of things off the top of my head:

- does elastic store the timezone when you insert a "date" type?
- when is it good to turn off indexing for a field?
- how can i speed up my queries for xyz application?
- when is it better to disable dynamic schema and enforce a schema for an Elastic index?
- does Elastic support constraints like a traditional SQL table?
- what is a good way to get GPS coordinates correctly auto-detected as GPS coordinate type in Elastic?

... rather than me thinking up questions. i looked at [the dba.stackexchange.com list of questions with the most upvotes and most of those questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) apply to Elastic too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While [elasticsearch](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch) is not off-topic here, there aren't a *lot* of questions being asked.  As such you may wait quite a while before getting a great answer.

Having said that, feel free to fire away!  The link above shows questions tagged on our main site with the elasticsearch tag.

Comment: thanks for the link. i should have thought to check the elasticsearch tag.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid the example questions you offer, on-topic or not, don't look like good candidates (for any SE site). They are either easily answerable by reading documentation (1, 5), opinion-based (2, 4, 6), or too broad (3).

If you come up with a good, properly researched, and answerable question, I'm sure someone will help.

Comment: Noting, of course, that the "too broad" nature of item 3 is based solely on the title - a proper question with more detail might be fine. Item 6, when fleshed out, might be an OK question (especially if changed from "What's a good way" to "How can I"); then again, this might be in the docs as well. That said, if the docs aren't helping you, and a trivial trial can't reveal the answer, I'd tend to think a question would be on topic.